# How to query a join table so that multiple criteria are met?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with 2 columns (see below).  A member can have multiple responses to a question:

```
RESPONSES
---------
member_id  INT
response_id  INT
```

```
SAMPLE DATA
member_id -- response_id
    1     --     3
    1     --     5
    2     --     1
    2     --     5
    2     --     9
    3     --     1
    3     --     5
    3     --     6
```

What I need to do is query the table for member that meet ALL response criteria.  For example I need to select all members that have a response_id of 1 AND 5.  I am using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_id 
FROM responses 
WHERE response_id = 1 AND response_id = 5
```

I would expect to get back member_id's 2 and 3.  However I am getting nothing returned.  I used EXPLAIN and it shows there is an error in my where query.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a function similar to IN where all the criteria must be met in order to return true?

Comment: As I see it, you need `OR` instead of `AND` there.

Comment: Your WHERE condition is applied to every row individually. As a result, it can never be true, because a column can't be equal to 1 and to 5 at the same time.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
SELECT member_ID
FROM responses
WHERE response_ID IN (1,5)
GROUP BY member_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT response_id) = 2
```

You need to count the number of records returned which is equal to the number of values supplied in your `IN` clause.

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eae45/11)

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT response_id) = 2` catches the case where the member has answered the same value twice.

Comment: @podiluska yeah right, i overlooked this phrase `member can have multiple responses to a question`. thanks to you.

Comment: It doesn't follow that a member can have multiple *identical* responses, though. Still, the OP doesn't clarify whether identical responses are possible or not, so it's better to be on the safe side and use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. But I would clarify in my answer that if multiple identical responses were guaranteed to be impossible, `COUNT(*)` would be preferable, as `DISTINCT` adds some overhead.